# APPCRASH on wpfgfx_v0400.dll only on 32-bit systems

Tags: wpf, crash, 32bit-64bit

I have an issue with a WPF application that I'm writing. I have a window that I load with profile pictures for the user to choose from when setting up an account within the application. Each picture is loaded into a user control, and placed in a stackpanel, so that when the user clicks the picture, it triggers the code in the user control, and automatically sets their profile picture without any more clicking needed. This window loads on 64-bit systems just fine. However, when loading on a 32-bit system, the entire application crashes. The faulting module is wpfgfx_v0400.dll. I don't know why it's crashing. Please help.

Here's the error in the Event Viewer:
[image]

Here's the XAML on the frontend of the window in question:

```
<Window x:Class="RandomApplication.Windows.ChooseProfilePic"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:RandomApplication.Windows"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
    ContentRendered ="On_ContentRendered"
    Title="Choose A Picture" Height="515" Width="500" Background="Black" ResizeMode="CanMinimize">
<Grid Background="Black">
    <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Height="420" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,5,0,0">
        <StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Name="HeadsPanel" Orientation="Horizontal" Height="100" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
            <StackPanel Name="AbstractPanel" Orientation="Horizontal" Height="100" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
            <StackPanel Name="ShapesPanel" Orientation="Horizontal" Height="100" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
            <StackPanel Name="MiscPanel" Orientation="Horizontal" Height="100" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
    <Button Name="CancelButton"  VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Style="{DynamicResource RedButton}" Click="CancelButton_Click">Cancel</Button>
    <Border Name="LoadingBorder" Background="Black">
        <TextBlock Name="LoadingLabel" Foreground="White" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,150" FontSize="20" FontWeight="Bold">
                <Run>Loading Pictures</Run>
                <LineBreak></LineBreak>
                <Run>Please Wait...</Run>
        </TextBlock>
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

Here's the code behind the window:

```
namespace RandomApplication.Windows
{
public partial class ChooseProfilePic : Window
{
    private readonly BackgroundWorker _loadPictureWorker = new BackgroundWorker();

    public ChooseProfilePic()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Topmost = true;

        _loadPictureWorker.DoWork += LoadImages;
        _loadPictureWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += LoadImages_Completed;
    }

    private void On_ContentRendered(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _loadPictureWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    private void CancelButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult = false;
        Close();
    }

    private void LoadImages(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            var headsImagePath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"Images\Profile Pics\Heads\";
            var abstractImagePath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"Images\Profile Pics\Abstract\";
            var shapesImagePath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"Images\Profile Pics\Shapes\";
            var miscImagePath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"Images\Profile Pics\Misc\";

            List<string> headsImageList = GetImages(headsImagePath);
            List<string> abstractImageList = GetImages(abstractImagePath);
            List<string> shapesImageList = GetImages(shapesImagePath);
            List<string> miscImageList = GetImages(miscImagePath);

            Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
            {
                LoadViewingPanel(headsImageList, HeadsPanel);
                LoadViewingPanel(abstractImageList, AbstractPanel);
                LoadViewingPanel(shapesImageList, ShapesPanel);
                LoadViewingPanel(miscImageList, MiscPanel);
            });
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            CustomMessageBox.Show("Could not load images. :-(", "Image Retrieval Failed", MessageBoxButton.OK,
                MessageBoxImage.Error);
            Helper.WriteException(Helper.ErrorLogs + "Error Loading Images.txt", ex);
        }
    }

    private void LoadImages_Completed(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Error != null)
        {
            CustomMessageBox.Show("Could not load images. :-(", "Image Retrieval Failed", MessageBoxButton.OK,
                MessageBoxImage.Error);
            Helper.WriteException(Helper.ErrorLogs + "Error Loading Images.txt", e.Error);
        }

        else LoadingBorder.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
    }

    public List<string> GetImages(string imagePath)
    {
        var that = GetAllFiles(imagePath);
        return that.ToList();
    }

    private void LoadViewingPanel(List<string> list, StackPanel panel)
    {
        foreach (var imageString in list)
        {
            Helper.WriteLineToFile(Helper.ErrorLogs + "2nd Info Loading Images.txt", imageString);
            var thisUri = new Uri(imageString, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
            var pic = new ProfilePic {ProfilePicImage = {Source = new BitmapImage(thisUri)}};
            panel.Children.Add(pic);
        }
    }

    private IEnumerable<string> GetAllFiles(string path)
    {
        return Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, "*.jpg").Union(
            Directory.EnumerateDirectories(path).SelectMany(d =>
            {
                try
                {
                    return GetAllFiles(d);
                }
                catch
                {
                    return Enumerable.Empty<string>();
                }
            }));
    }
}
}
```

I've researched what could cause issues with this particular dll, but none of it seems to relate to my issue.

Answer (score 0):

So, I figured out the issue. Apparently, the size of the images that I was trying to load was too big. The images were all 2048x2048 pixels, which made them anywhere from 180 KB to 380 KB in size. Apparently this is too much. I resized all of the pictures to 100x100 pixels (as I was only ever presenting them to the user as 100x100), which brought the file sizes down to 7 - 10 KB each. After that, they loaded just fine with no crashing issues.